# concatenation of data into superset

Tags: apache-superset

there are two tables, one collects facts on a daily basis, the other on a monthly basis with the same set of attributes (for example, region, city, technology).
I need to calculate the formula in a superset

```
SUM(t1.count_exp) / SUM(t2.count_base)
```

which will be correctly visualized when calculating by region, or by city, or by region + city + technology per month.
in other bi systems, the **group by** is performed first, then the **join** is executed and the formula above is calculated, which gives the desired result. How to achieve a similar result in a superset?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming both tables are in same database, then you can write your own query joining the two tables in 'SQL Lab' and then visualize the query results using 'Explore' option available there.

Once you click on 'Explore' from SQL Lab, Superset will create a Virtual Dataset(Table) inside Superset from results of SQL query. Any filters/group by/limit applied on this virtual table from visualization will query over this query.

https://superset.apache.org/docs/frequently-asked-questions

> A view is a simple logical layer that abstract an arbitrary SQL
> queries as a virtual table. This can allow you to join and union
> multiple tables, and to apply some transformation using arbitrary SQL
> expressions. The limitation there is your database performance as
> Superset effectively will run a query on top of your query (view). A
> good practice may be to limit yourself to joining your main large
> table to one or many small tables only, and avoid using GROUP BY where
> possible as Superset will do its own GROUP BY and doing the work twice
> might slow down performance.